# Linking from a html page to a controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets, model-view-controller

I want to place a link on some text in a html page so that when the text is clicked, it will link to a controller method which will return a different html to the screen. Any ideas how I can do this anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: OnClick event, do you want to forward to a different html page (or) do you want to get HTML from the controller and display it in current page?

Comment: forward it to a different html. thanks :)

Comment: I have edited your tags based on how I understand your question. If this is truly a Java (not Javascript) question, let me know

Comment: when reffering to the MVC you create servlet based app?

Comment: @ControlAltDel it is java in my controller html and css on the page

Comment: @mastah yes servlet based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to forward to another HTML page, onClick of text, then all you need is [a simple HTML  tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
```

If you want to do some logic, before forward it to another page, then you can either use JavaScript (or) Servlets (or) Some MVC framework such as Struts to do the required operation.

Comment: i wanna link to a method within my controller. not directly to the html, sorry if i confused you.

Comment: @Shaun You can do that by using Servlets. Read more about Servlets here. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: ok so basically i got it working by using the following link template:http://[host]:[port][request-path] from the link provided by @K139. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Considering OP meaned Java - your anchor tag

```
  <a href="mypage/MyServlet?myparam=1">asdasd</a>
```

based on this, your servlet with url-pattern matching MyServlet, should check it in a doGet method like:

```
  if(request.getParameter("myparam")!=null && request.getParameter("myparam")==1){
  //outside website or your JSP page
  response.sendRedirect("http://google.com");
  //for more control on jsp pages
  request.getRequestDispacher("your.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

}